# SQL multiple condition case when

Tags: case

SQL Case When - I have a column with job status options B & D. I want to create a case when SQL statement that will check and retrieve employee IDs with both statuses in the column. In thise case shown it should only return John Doe, not Doe John or John Jr.

[image]

Comment: Please provide scripts for table creation and data.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be using having clause.

The following example would work on most DBMS (tested on MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server).

```
select name
from my_table
where job_status in ('B','D')
group by name
having count(distinct job_status) = 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/RigcWJsd

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTERSECT` for that:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM dbo.NotProvidedTableName
WHERE [Job Status] = 'B'
INTERSECT
SELECT [Name]
FROM dbo.NotProvidedTableName
WHERE [Job Status] = 'D';
```

Next time, please don't add pictures of data, but provide scripts to create tables and testdata.

Additional reading about INTERSECT:
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/intersect.php